# Remove commas in a string, surrounded by a comma and double quotes / Python

Tags: python, regex

I've found some similar themes on stackoverflow, but I'm newbie to Python and Reg Exps.

I have a string

> ,"Completely renovated in 2009, the 2-star Superior Hotel Ibis Berlin
>   Messe, with its 168 air-conditioned rooms, is located right next to
>   Berlin's ICC and exhibition center. All rooms have Wi-Fi, and you can
>   surf the Internet free of charge at two iPoint-PCs in the lobby. We
>   provide a 24-hour bar, snacks and reception service. Enjoy our
>   breakfast buffet from 4am to 12pm on the 8th floor, where you have a
>   fantastic view across Berlin. You will find free car parking directly
>   next to the hotel.",

A pattern should be like: `comma, double quote|any text with commas |double quote, comma`.
I need to replace commas in double quotes, for example with `@` character.
Which reg exp pattern should I use?

I tried this :

```
r',"([.*]*,[.*]*)*",'
```

with different variations, but it doesn't work.

Thanks for the answers, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is replace commas with the @ character you should look into doing a `str_replace` rather than regex.

```
str_a = "Completely renovated in 2009, the 2-star Superior Hotel Ibis Berlin Messe, with its 168 air-conditioned rooms, is located right next to Berlin's ICC and exhibition center. All rooms have Wi-Fi, and you can surf the Internet free of charge at two iPoint-PCs in the lobby. We provide a 24-hour bar, snacks and reception service. Enjoy our breakfast buffet from 4am to 12pm on the 8th floor, where you have a fantastic view across Berlin. You will find free car parking directly next to the hotel."

str_a = str_a.replace('","', '@') #commas inside double quotes
str_a = str_a.replace(',', '@') #replace just commas

print str_a
```

Edit: Alternatively you could make a list of what you want to replace, then loop through it and perform the replacement. Ex:

```
to_replace = ['""', ',', '"']

str_a = "Completely renovated in 2009, the 2-star Superior Hotel Ibis Berlin Messe, with its 168 air-conditioned rooms, is located right next to Berlin's ICC and exhibition center. All rooms have Wi-Fi, and you can surf the Internet free of charge at two iPoint-PCs in the lobby. We provide a 24-hour bar, snacks and reception service. Enjoy our breakfast buffet from 4am to 12pm on the 8th floor, where you have a fantastic view across Berlin. You will find free car parking directly next to the hotel."

for a in to_replace:
    str_a = str_a.replace(a, '@')

print str_a
```

Comment: This won't work in case there are multiple strings enclosed within double quotes.

Comment: When you loop through the `to_replace` make a sub loop that loops through all your strings.

Comment: @RohitJain or do you want to replace the entire set of text (not just the quotes) with the @ symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, your regex is suspicious.

```
,"([.*]*,[.*]*)*",
```

`[.*]` will match either a literal dot or an asterisk (`.` and `*` become literals in character classes).

Additionally, if this could actually match something in the string, you would be able to replace only one comma, because the rest of the string (comma included) would have been consumed by the regex and once consumed, cannot be substituted again, unless you run a loop until there's no more commas to replace.

What you can do with `re.sub` and replace those commas is to use lookarounds (you can google it, there's enough documentation about them I believe). If you have only one pair of double quotes, you can make sure that only commas followed by one double quote are replaced:

```
,(?=[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

`[^"]` means a character which is not a double quote. `[^"]*` means that this will repeat 0 or more times.

The `$` is to mean the end of the line.

Now, the lookahead `(?= ... )` makes sure that there's what's inside in front of the comma.

See the commas that match [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/cA1aF9).

After that, you can simply replace the commas by whichever value you want.

```
str = re.sub(r',(?=[^"]*"[^"]*$)', '@', str)
```

If however there are multiple double quotes, you should make sure that there are an odd number of double quotes ahead. This can be done by using the regex:

```
,(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

`(?: ... )` by the way is a non-capture group.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (quite deadly though). The trick here is that, any character inside a pair of *double quotes*, is followed by odd number of double quotes, assuming of course, your double quotes are balanced:

```
s = 'some comma , outside "Some comma , inside" , "Completely , renovated in 2009",'

import re
s = re.sub(r',(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', "@", s)
print s
```

**Output**:

```
some comma , outside "Some comma @ inside" , "Completely @ renovated in 2009",
```

Answer (score 2):

If the pattern is always as stated, the following code snippet will do what you want:

```
text = ',' + text[1:-2].replace(',', '@') + ','
```

## Discussion

- `text[1:-2]` will give you the original string, minus the first and last characters (the commas)
- We then call `.replace()` to turn all the commas to at signs
- Finally, we put back the first and last commas to form the resulting string