# Replace a comma in text values in CSV using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++, dynamics-crm-2013

I searched a lot but couldn't find any exact soluion.

I have a CSV which contains some values that contains a comma in between the values.
Following is a sample row

> "BEIAAGJIPAMBPJIF",2757,08042010,"13:53.59",09042010,"01:55.39","SIHAM","BEIAIGHEIPLGPJIF",20,"A",20,"S",0.00,0.00,0.00,"OLY
>   SPECIAL ORDER","IN STOCK , DESIGNER",0.00000,0,"","N","N",

Now it you look at the value `"IN STOCK , DESIGNER"`, it containts a comma in between. due to which while reading the csv in my .net application and in MS Dynamics CRM import file wizard, it breaks it into two seprate values instead of one single value.

I need a regex that can match such strings and replace the comma with a hyphen "-" that I can use in Notepad ++.

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: The CSV format allows the delimiter to be present in your field value if the field is quoted. So if your app can't read it correctly, your app is wrong/wrongly configured. Make sure that `,` is set up as delimiter and `"` is set up as quotechar, then it should work.

Comment: If you really need a regex solution, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18236235/1578604) could help. The last regex I mentioned matches a comma which is within quotes. Just replace by `-` as can be seen [here](http://regex101.com/r/pG1jD1) (note this regex assumes there are no escaped quotes).

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me, although it is a bit indirect:

1. by searching, detect character which is unused in the file, e.g. `#`
2. use the following **regex** replace to replace all delimiters:  find: `(".*?"|.*?),`  replace: `\1#` (note the character from step 1)
3. now, all leftover commas are only those which are inside the quotes. Mass replace them for `-`
4. replace back all `#`'s for commas